# Sending parameters to ckfinder with the config options

Tags: php, amazon-s3, ckeditor, ckfinder

I have set up CKEditor and CKFinder and integrated both, uploading files with a s3 backend works well.

I now need to send the S3 bucket name where the file should be uploaded as a parameter so that files from different organisations (schools in this case) end up in different buckets.

For testing I am modifying the `config.js` file in ckfinder folder. Once it works I will move configuration options in the `setupCKEditor()` method.

```
CKFinder.setupCKEditor(null, {pass:"bucket", token:"nameofbucket"});
```

Here is what I have in the `config.js` file for now :

```
var config = {};

config.pass = 'bucket';
config.token = 'nameofbucket';

CKFinder.define( config );
```

Here is what's in the `config.php` file to get the parameter :

```
if (isset($_GET['bucket'])) {
    $bucketname = $_GET['bucket'];
} else {
    $bucketname = "buckethasnoname";
}
```

No matter what I try I cant get the value of the parameter and end up with buckethasnoname in my URL. I have tried using [connectorInfo](http://docs.cksource.com/ckfinder3/#!/api/CKFinder.Config-cfg-connectorInfo) as well but to the same results.

How can I send extra parameters to ckfinder ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to give the comma separated list of keys of the additional parameters (*token* in your case) in the pass config.

Just change *token* to *bucket*. And your code should work fine.

```
var config = {};

config.pass = 'bucket';
config.bucket = 'nameofbucket';

CKFinder.define( config );
```

Just adding one more info. You can pass multiple parameters like this.

```
    var config = {};

    config.pass = 'bucket,path';
    config.bucket = 'nameofbucket';
    config.path = 'somepath';

    CKFinder.define( config );
```

For more details, [Refer this documentation](https://docs-old.ckeditor.com/ckfinder3/#!/api/CKFinder.Config)

Comment: This just flat did not work for me, and I never figured out why... :(